Как отправить видео через TeleBot?
У меня возникла проблема при отправке видео. Телеграм почему то блокирует отправку видео выше чем 50мб. Но как обойти это? Пробовал даже send_document, но не помогло. Помогите

Это ограничение телеграм.
Используйте Local Bot API Server

Using a Local Bot API Server The Bot API server source code is
available at telegram-bot-api. You can run it locally and send the
requests to your own server instead of https://api.telegram.org. If
you switch to a local Bot API server, your bot will be able to:
Download files without a size limit. Upload files up to 2000 MB.
Upload files using their local path and the file URI scheme. Use an
HTTP URL for the webhook. Use any local IP address for the webhook.
Use any port for the webhook. Set max_webhook_connections up to
100000. Receive the absolute local path as a value of the file_path field without the need to download the file after a getFile request.

Также, смотря как вы отправляете. Можно загрузить файл и отправлять по file_id, в этом случае ограничение работать не будет

Отправка видео через библиотеку telebot может быть реализована с помощью метода send_video. Вот пример кода:
import telebot

TOKEN = 'YOUR_TELEGRAM_BOT_TOKEN'
bot = telebot.TeleBot(TOKEN)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['send_video'])
def send_video(message):
    video_file = open('path/to/video.mp4', 'rb')
    bot.send_video(message.chat.id, video=video_file)

bot.polling()


А вы пробовали этим кодом отправить видео больше чем 50мб?
